# AWS CloudFormation and Elastic Transcoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Does AWS CloudFormation allow creating templated for AWS Elastic Transcoder?

PS: I tried creating a DataPipeline, but no that is not the same as Transcoder pipeline

Answer (score 4):

Not yet. The following page shows all available resource types for AWS Cloudformation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use a python lambda function wrapped in a custom resource.  With Lambda support in custom resources, services/features not currently supported can be accommodated in the template.

This github project shows how

```
https://github.com/mazerte/aws-cloudformation-elastic-transcoder-pipeline
```